# Connect data in two classes for use in a View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, collections

I am trying to bind an IEnumberable collection to a combobox. I know that the problem is where I am instantiating my ViewModel... The datacontext of my view is a totally different instance and is not seeing the data that is being set.I need to know how I need to pass over the data to the right instance. I am new to WPF so I may not being explaining some of this completely right. Below is the code that I find to be relevant. If you want to see anything else, just let me know and I will try my best to provide the information. Any help would be appreciated! I also will always accept tips and tricks!

Code:

XAML:

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="cboProviders" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=AddressProviders}" DisplayMemberPath="ProviderName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAddressProvider, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Above is the binding that I am currently using. It knows that there is a collection there but it does not show the data that is being set.

DataContext:

```
public EmailAddressWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new EmailViewModel();

        }
```

This is set to the EmailViewModel

EmailViewModel:

```
   public IEnumerable<IEmailAddressesProvider> AddressProviders 
    {
        get
        {
            return _AddressProviders;
        }
        set
        {
            _AddressProviders = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AddressProviders");
        }
    }
private string _SelectedAddressProvider;
public string SelectedAddressProvider
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedAddressProvider;
    }
    set
    {
        _SelectedAddressProvider = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedAddressProvider");
    }
}
```

Interface (IEmailAddressesProvider):

```
    public interface IEmailAddressesProvider
    {
        string ProviderName { get; }
        IEnumerable<EmailAddress> GetEmailUsers();
    }
}
```

Where the ProviderName is set and the EmailUsers method is defined (EmailAddressesProvider):

```
[Export(typeof(IEmailAddressesProvider))]
    public class EmailAddressProvider : IEmailAddressesProvider
    {
        #region Private Properties

        private static readonly IEncryptionService encryptionService = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IEncryptionService>();

        #endregion

        public string ProviderName
        {
            get { return "Alliance Users"; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<EmailAddress> GetEmailUsers()
        {
            IUserRepository userRepo = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<IUserRepository>();
            IEnumerable<User> users = userRepo.GetAllUsers().Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false).OrderBy(a => a.UserID).AsEnumerable();

            List<EmailAddress> AddressList = new List<EmailAddress>();

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                if (user.DisplayName != null && user.EmailAddress != null && user.DisplayName != string.Empty && user.EmailAddress != string.Empty)
                    AddressList.Add(new EmailAddress() { DisplayName = encryptionService.DecryptString(user.DisplayName), Email = encryptionService.DecryptString(user.EmailAddress) });
            }

            AddressList.OrderBy(u => u.DisplayName);

            return AddressList;

        }
    }
```

Where is is being set to the ViewModel (EmailService.cs)

```
[ImportMany]
        public IEnumerable<IEmailAddressesProvider> AddressProviders { get; set; }

 EmailView ev = AllianceApp.Container.GetExportedValue<EmailView>();


            ev.ViewModel.AddressProviders = this.AddressProviders;
```

As you can see here, the view being used is EmailView... However I need to be using the View defined in the datacontext of my window where the combobox is. Do I need to somehow connect the classes to share the information. If so, how in the world do I do that. This might not even be the problem, but it is the only thing that made sense to me. Hopefully one of you can figure it out before I throw my computer.. Again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Throwing things is why I buy my own wireless mice and keyboards at work...

Comment: Ha! I actually broke my mouse the other day. The joys of learning on the go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms668604.aspx)  for binding, if you already have the collection as an `IEnumerable` you can easily convert it,

```
ObservableCollection<T> obsColl = new ObservableCollection<T>(originalIEnumerable)
```

`ObservableCollection` has a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable` as a parameter and makes a shallow copy of it

Comment: They really like to use IEnumerable here for some reason... so I need to try to keep it that way if possible.

Comment: Could you explain how this would solve my problem? I am having to use a value that is exported from another View which is why my data is not showing up

Comment: @JLott In your Model, you can create an ObservableCollection property and bind it to the view,use the constructor to convert IEnumerable to Observable.

Comment: @Jlott The problem seems not to be that your ViewModel doesn't know when the collection changes, it's that it isn't being notified that the *contents* of the collection are changed. Switching to ObservableCollection should resolve this. Also IEnunerable is an interface - which ObservableCollection implements - so ObservableCollection *is an* IEnunerable.