# Pros and Cons of using Observable Collection over IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, ienumerable, observablecollection

I am trying to decide if I want to switch all of my `IEnumerable` collections over to Observable Collections. I cannot find a good explanation of this. What are the Pros and Cons of the Observable Collection in understandable terms?

Comment: As a minor side note: Observables implement IEnumerable as well. They just have the added benefit that they can be set up to be monitored by the UI as well.

Comment: Closed? Respectfully disagree with that vote. This is perfectly within the scope of "I would like others to explain _______ to me"  as noted in the FAQ, and identifies specific elements for which the OP is requesting explanation. There have been several good, detailed answers which I think demonstrate the "not constructive" closure is inappropriate. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Thank you @David W. I was a bit confused myself on why it was closed..

Comment: @JLott You're welcome. Don't know if it will help, but one has to try sometimes :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may decide to have `IEnumerable<Something>` as type of some property, but use `ObservableCollection<Something>` as the actual value.

If you have a property like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Something> collectionOfSomething;
public IEnumerable<Something> CollectionOfSomething
{
    get { return collectionOfSomething; }
    set
    {
        collectionOfSomething = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("CollectionOfSomething");
    }
}
```

Now you may simply assign to that property like

```
someViewModelObject.CollectionOfSomething = new ObservableCollection<Something>();
```

---

When you assign or bind to a collection property (for example `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`), the target object usually checks whether the actual property value implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (what `ObservableCollection` does) and attaches a `CollectionChanged` handler to get notified about changes in the source collection.

If you later decide to have some other, smarter implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged` you do not need to change all your property types. Just replace the assignment(s) by something like this

```
someViewModelObject.CollectionOfSomething = new MyVerySmartCollection<Something>();
```

Comment: Hmmm this is actually really helpful.. I might mess around with it for a while. It might solve the problems that I have been having with the IEnumerable. Thanks!\

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably frame the answer to your question this way: Does your application need to be notified when your collections change content? If so, then such a change is possibly warranted. My understanding is that the overarching feature of Observable collections is that they provide a mechanism for notifications when the collection changes, whereas IEnumerable provides only a single-iteration enumerator.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The largest benefit to using ObservableCollection is it implements INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged, automatically, which makes it simpler to data-bind. I would say that it's better to use ObservableCollection when you are first setting up your data-bindings.

But now that you have already coded up (and data-bound?) a bunch of IEnumerables, there isn't any savings to be had, at this point.

Another thing to consider is that `ObservableCollection<T>` *is an* `IEnumerable` (Inherited from `Collection<T>`). Since `IEnumerable` is an interface, it is implemented by many classes `List<T>` is one such class - `ObservableCollection<T>` is another.

Comment: I like @Clemens example which shows in code the differences as far as data-binding is concerned. So, maybe all of your future additions to the project can benefit from `ObservableCollecion<T>`

Comment: I have not bounded them yet... I am having problems with that because I am having to use the value from another view, and the view I am working in cannot see that data. I heard that changing it to an observable collection could fix it, but I am still not entirely sure.. Here is a link to my previous question that led to this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836678/connect-data-in-two-classes-for-use-in-a-view/14836935#comment20791174_14836935

Answer (score 1):

The entire point of Observable collections is that they implement the following interfaces

```
 INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

This makes it very easy to alert the UI/ViewModel of changes and update accordingly.  If you didn't use ObservableCollection you would be required to implement the updates to the collection/properties yourself manually.