# Comparison of Collections for ListBox and ComboBoxes

Tags: c#

I have seen this post 
[Pros and Cons of using Observable Collection over IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837834/pros-and-cons-of-using-observable-collection-over-ienumerable)

My Questions are for ComboBoxes/ListBoxes :

Is there a summary of what type of collections could be used in this kind of binding, I mean which collection type can be used for binding to an ItemsSource for ListBoxes/ComboBoxes Kind. Which interfaces does each of these collection has to implement in order to be able to be bound to an ItemsSource
Does any of these Collection offer certain disadvantage/advantages over the other in terms of rendering speed and async advantages, lets say with virtualization set to on? Or it does not matter once the ItemsSource has been set?

1. Enumerable
2. ReadOnlyCollection
3. ObservableCollection
4. ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer the speed comparison you ask for since the things listed are completely different things.

Let me explain that briefly:

`IEnumerable` is just an interface that provides you with a bunch of extension methods and iterator functionality. Notable collection classes that implement `IEnumerable` would be e.g. a `Dictionary<>`, or an `ObservableCollection<>` or a `List<>` for that matter.

`ReadOnlyCollection` (and I assume you don't mean `IReadOnlyCollection`) is a concrete implementation of `IReadOnlyCollection` that wraps around an existing class that implements the `IList` interface. You pass that into the constructor and it will give you read only access to the content of the collection.

`ObservableCollection` implements among other things `IEnumerable` and `IList` interfaces.

Assuming from the context of your question you ask if there are specific collections that you can bind to `ComboBoxe`s or `ListBoxe`s and alike that are preferable in terms of speed.

Let's look at the WPF `ComboBox`:

Its `ItemsSource` property asks for an `IEnumerable`, and as stated above you can use any concrete class that implements that interface. You mentioned `ObservableCollection`, that one is interesting because it implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

It allows you to do the following: Once you have an `ObservableCollection` bound to the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` if you e.g. `Add()` or `Remove()` items from it the `ComboBox` will get notified of the change and reflect that by adding, or removing items from the list of visible things in the dropdown. If you used e.g. a `List<>` instead that would not happen and you would have to rebind/reassign the `ItemsSource` again.

Let's get back to the speed question, we can break that down into several parts:

1. Construction of your collection:
   A List will be cheaper to construct than an `ObservableCollection`
   simply because of the fact that Observable collection has to
   repeatedly raise the `CollectionChanged` event. So if you know that
   you collection never changes and you can construct it completely
   before you assign it to the `ItemsSource` you can use a `List`
   instead.
2. Maintainance of the collection: As mentioned in 1. if the collection never changes and can be pre-constructed, don't use an `ObservableCollection`, use the List
   instead
3. (Probably most interesting for you) Rendering of items: Depending on the Container (e.g. `ListBox` or `ComboBox` or any other for that matter) the largest amount of time will be spent
   rendering the items unless the control virtualizes the items.

--What does #3 that mean?
Imagine you have a collection of 300 items and assign that to your container:

- If it is not virtualized it will start rendering all 300 items which takes a while but you will likely only see a subset of them on the screen all the other ones are hidden and you have to move a scrollbar to get them into view.
- If the control can virtualize it will render only the part you can see right now and maybe a couple extra directly adjacent and then when you scroll start rendering the ones that come into view on demand. This is significantly faster initially and maybe a little bit slower during scrolling.

Points 1 and 2 are likely very negligible for such small lists with 300 items, however you will likely want to look into #3. Even already for smaller datasets virtualization makes a huge difference because most of the time is spent rendering especially if you have complex/slow Styles or DataTemplates

This might not directly answer your question but will instead give you a hint into which direction to focus your efforts.

Comment: Thank you Frank, Now I understand a lot more. I am new to WPF. I am liking C#, it seems to have a lot of solutions for most problems that I have.